# How do I remove '<br />' elements I have added with insertBefore()?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I am working on a responsive site and when the screen reaches a certain size, I want to add some breaklines before an element to move stuff around. I have accomplished that with this.

```
jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    var WINDOW = jQuery(window).width();

    console.log(WINDOW)

    if (WINDOW < 1025) {
        jQuery('<br /><br />').insertBefore('#FILTER_ADVANCED');
    }

});
```

Is there any way to remove these breaklines when the window goes back above 1025? I guess I'm looking for the opposite of insertBefore().

I want to be able to resize the browser and watch everything jump into place, pointless I know, but the fact I can't do it is annoying me.

Thanks.

Can I encapsulate jQuery inside a media query?

Comment: Side note: Please try to be consistent, either use `$` or `jQuery`.

Comment: Have you tried using CSS to pad out the content instead of using break lines?

Comment: Instead of using line breaks, try using CSS to add margins or padding to create that space you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ive tried every CSS method I can think of. I wanted to avoid jQuery to be honest, but it's really my last option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blunt solution. Something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var WINDOW = $(window).width();

    console.log(WINDOW)

    if (WINDOW < 1025) {
        jQuery('<br /><br />').insertBefore('#FILTER_ADVANCED');
    } else {
        jQuery("#FILTER_ADVANCED").prev("br").remove();
        jQuery("#FILTER_ADVANCED").prev("br").remove();
    }

});
```

Comment: Blunt but effective! Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that a 'reponsive' design doesn't mean it responds to the user changing the size of their screen, but displays well on different sized screens (i.e. mobile vs desktop).

You could use CSS to do the same, having a css rule something like this (I think. I don't do much css):

```
// big screen - no padding
@media (min-width:1024px) 
{ 
  #FILTER_ADVANCED padding-top: 0px
}

// small screen - some padding
@media (max-width:1024px) 
{ 
  #FILTER_ADVANCED padding-top: 10px
}
```

Comment: I am aware of that. Already using media queries, but I'm working on someone else's code which was never intended to be responsive, so I'm having to hack and slash at it to get it to do what I want.